# Get Sharepoint page library list id

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am working on a custom solution where a for current page of page library I am doing some logic on edit mode.

I wish to get the id of the current page.Is there any in built way to get it in JavaScript object model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `_spPageContextInfo` object which you can use to access all the page related properties.

So it has below structure

```
_spPageContextInfo 
{
    webServerRelativeUrl : "/ProjectWeb",
    webLanguage : 1033,
    currentLanguage : 1033,
    webUIVersion : 4,
    pageListId : "{c1d7b89f-f07b-4e2e-b89c-76c315831d59}",
    pageItemId : 5,
    userId : 68,
    alertsEnabled : true,
    siteServerRelativeUrl : "/",
    allowSilverlightPrompt : "True"
}
```

So you can use `_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId` to get the current page id.

Hope this helps.